# plotting issue with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphing

I have an issue with plotting a graph over some values in python and matplotlib. What i want is to plot the i's (iterations) on the x-axis and optimal q*'s on the y-axis in the code below.

```
    #Question 1 

#i)
#Defining the parameters using SimpleNameSpace. par = Parameters
par = SimpleNamespace()
par.y = 1 #assets
par.p = 0.2 #probability
par.theta = -2 #elasticity 

#Defining utility function for agent
def utility(z,par):
    return (z**(1+par.theta))/(1+par.theta)

#Defining premium
def premium(q,par):
    return par.p*q

#Defining expected value
#Note that z_1, z_2 represents first and second part of the objective function - just in a compressed version
def exp_value (i,q,par):
    z_1 = par.y-i+q-premium(q,par)
    z_2 = par.y-premium(q,par)
    return par.p*utility(z_1,par)+(1-par.p)*utility(z_2,par)

def opt_q(i,par):
    obj = lambda q: -exp_value(i,q,par) #defining the objective function
    solution = minimize_scalar(obj, bounds=(0,0.9), method='bounded') #bounded solution within [0, 0.9] 
    q = solution.x 
    return q

# ii), iii) Creating a for loop to make a grid of the optimum q
for i in np.linspace(0.01,0.9,num=100):
    res = opt_q(i,par)
    print(res)
    
#iv) plotting the is and q*s with matplotlib

plt.plot(res,i)

# function to show the plot
plt.show()
```

When i run the above code i get nothing out on the graph. Can somebody explain what is missing?

Comment: `i` is a loop variable, it's just the last value after the loop (0.9). Try `plt.plot(res, np.linspace(0.01, 0.9, 100))`

Comment: Hi @LukasNeugebauer, thank you for your reply. Unfortunately i get this error: 'ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (100,)'

Comment: Ah, you're also only storing the last value in res. define it before as a list and append the value of each iteration. You might want to look up Python basics.